# htaccess cannot rewrite to proper URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/articles/([0-9]+)/$ /article-one.html?aid=$1 [L]
```

from SEO friendly URL eg.

```
https://example.com/articles/99/aaaa-aabbbb-bb-cccccccc
```

rewrite to

```
https://example.com/article-one.html?aid=99
```

why does it not work?

Comment: In .htaccess context, the URL path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already.

Comment: And your rule demands the path _ends_ after the digits and slash, but your example URL has additional text after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ^/articles/([0-9]+)/$
> ```

In a *directory* context (ie. `.htaccess`) the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. However, this would only match URLs of the form `/articles/99/`, not `/articles/99/aaaa-aabbbb-bb-cccccccc` - as stated in your example.

You would need to modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to something like the following instead:

```
^articles/([0-9]+)/[\w-]*$
```

This specifically matches an *optional* trailing *slug* of the form `aaaa-aabbbb-bb-cccccccc` (no trailing slash). If you simply wanted to ignore *anything* that comes after the numeric path segment then just remove the trailing `$` (end-of-string anchor). For example:

```
^articles/([0-9]+)/
```

Comment: Thx MrWhite; Next problem what occured is: how redirect from such url https://example.com/articles/99/aaaa-aabbbb-bb-cccccccc to simple call article-one.html / this formula RewriteRule /article/ article-one.html not working

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - that looks pretty much the same as what you were trying to do above, except `/article/` has no `s`?